# In .NET is it faster to use the Attribute suffix even though it is not required?

Tags: .net, attributes

[MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(VS.71).aspx#vcwlkattributestutorialanchor2) that

> you do not need to specify the
>   attribute suffix when using attributes
>   in code

Example: You have an attribute named `HelpAttribute`. You can decorate a property with `[Help]` (no Attribute suffix) or with `[HelpAttribute]`; either is allowable. But, does the code run faster when you use the full attribute name rather than the non-suffixed name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code compiles down to the exact same IL and has 0 runtime performance difference.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference, its a syntax feature to save you typing Attribute all the time.

Answer (score 2):

it is a compiler feature, result IL will be the same